# Unexpected behaviour with CKEditor and jquery deferred in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using jquery deferred to call the `setReadOnly()` after the editor has been initialized and is ready. So, I have

```
editor.on('instanceReady', function () {
    _ckeditorInitDeferred.resolve(editor);
});
```

When using deferred to call `setReadOnly()`, that was giving me a 'Permission denied' error in IE.

However, if I have `setReadonly()` in the function on `instanceReady` instead, that does not give me the error message.

```
editor.on('instanceReady', function () {
    editor.setReadOnly();
   _ckeditorInitDeferred.resolve(editor);
});
```

I searched and wasn't able to find any explanation for why this works and when using jquery deferred I get permission denied. Has anyone seen this before? Or know if IE has some kind of limitation ?

EDIT:

_ckeditorInitDeferred is the deferred object

```
_ckeditorInitDeferred = $.Deferred();
```

this is the function to disable the editor when the editor instance is ready and the _ckeditorInitDeferred.resolve() is called.

```
this.disable = function () {

function doDisable() {

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[_editorId];
    if (!editor) {
      return;
    }

    editor.updateElement();
    editor.setReadOnly();

}
_ckeditorInitDeferred.done(doDisable);

};
```

Comment: can you initialize editor once deferred is resolved instead of on page load?

Comment: all the deferred does is to wait until editor is initialized then set the editor to readonly

Comment: Can you provide your full code? what's _ckeditorInitDeferred?

Comment: _ckeditorInitDeferred is the deferred object.
_ckeditorInitDeferred = $.Deferred();

Comment: It would be much better if you provide a full example, not partial code. I see there a new variable _editorId instead of using the editor object that you pass to .resolve(), and in the doDisable you're calling updateElement that you didn't call in the working sample